# return(exit) in Controller on Codeigniter （Early termination）（with Twig Template Engine）

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I was told that if I write a return in the controller, it will loop and cause an error on Codeigniter.

For example, is it inappropriate to write(return view) as follows in Controller?

```
public function example {
    // ...
    if (some conditions ...) {
        return $this->twig->display('templates/error.html');
    }

    return $this->twig->display('templates/success.html');
}
```

I'm not familiar with Codeigniter.
I considered the return value to be a problem in Controller and corrected it as follows.

```
public function example {
    // ...
    if (some conditions ...) {
        $this->twig->display('templates/error.html');
        return;
    }

    $this->twig->display('templates/success.html');
    return;
}
```

The older version of Codeigniter may also be affecting...
(Codeigniter 2.1.3 and PHP 5.3.3 and Twig 1.36.* )
Those who mention the location of the error are not sure about it.
Errors rarely occur（ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE）.

What I want to check is if there is no problem with the above-mentioned writing method in Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by inappropriate you mean "will it cause errors" and the answer is no. The error those users are experiencing is usually due to connection issues on their end, or a server issue unrelated to php.

CodeIgniter in their docs even uses controller methods with return statements as a means for form validation callbacks, so it isn't unheard of.

That being said, I'm not entirely sure why you even need these return statements. `exit()` would be more appropriate if you wanted to the script to stop.

Comment: Because I received an indication, I was worry that should not write a return in Controller on Codeigniter.  
Thank you. I was relieved to hear that I could write a return.  
In this case, I wanted to switch views by processing.  
In the case of `exit()`, it seems that the view is not called(blank page), so I wrote a return.